# What is the Best way to host a Xmpp Server?

Tags: xmpp

What is the best way to host a dedicated Xmpp server, looking for something that is applicable for testing a product in beta around 200-300 users .

Was also wondering whether Mediatemple's dedicated virtual would be good enough ?

Answer (score 3):

Openfire works for me: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

Comment: Yeah, may be I didnt pharse it well. We use openfire but we need our own openfire server :) . We are right now using jabber.org and the speeds are really not satisfying.

Comment: Vineet, you can download and deploy your own copy of Openfire on your own systems.  In fact, with a commercial license you can deploy it on multiple systems.  We use this in our organization with roughly 50 users on a fairly underpowered system (Dell SC1425) and it has no issues.

Answer (score 1):

With the scarcity of constraints you express, I'd suggest [openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) (Java) or [pretzel](http://code.google.com/p/pretzel/) (Python + Twisted) -- no experience with Mediatemple to compare.  If you express more constraints or requirements, maybe the answers can be more helpful!-)

Comment: Alex, 

I think the idea and may be I didnt phrase the question right was that we do use the openfire server which is hosted on jabber.org. What we need is now to host it and use dv server. Not sure which one works best.

Comment: @Vineet, if your questions are related to system administration and not to programming, consider asking on serverfault rather than on stackoverflow (superuser might also be appropriate).  This site is strictly about programming, and in that optic I'm saying that it depends on what language you want to use, e.g., openfire for Java, pretzel for Python (and so on, no doubt, but I wouldn't know what's best for, say, Erlang!-).

Answer (score 1):

I've used [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) on Amazon EC2, Slicehost and prgmr servers with no problem whatsoever - though it does help to know Erlang for the configuration files and log files.

If you need to federate your server (e.g. to Google Chat and/or jabber.org) then you'll need a valid SSL certificate for it - the [XMPP Standards Foundation](http://xmpp.net) is one way to get one.